# Do i have to open a new DB connection for every write in Cassandra?

Tags: java, database, cassandra, connection

I am trying to write a simple JAVA program which generates some data (just a POJO) which gets published in an Kafka topic. From this topic, a subscriber fetches the data and should write it into a Cassandra DB.

The producing and fetching is working fine but when it comes to writing the data into the Cassandra DB, there is something that makes me wondering.

When i am trying to write the data, i always have to open a new connection to the DB. The looks very unpleasant.

```
 @Override
  public void run() {

    setRunning(true);


    try {
      konsument.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(ServerKonfiguration.TOPIC));

      while (running) {

        ConsumerRecords<Long, SensorDaten> sensorDaten = konsument.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        sensorDaten.forEach(
                datum -> {
                  CassandraConnector cassandraConnector = new CassandraConnector();

                  cassandraConnector.schreibeSensorDaten(datum.key(), datum.value());
                  System.out.printf(
                          "Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n",
                          datum.key(), datum.value(), datum.partition(), datum.offset());
                });
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      konsument.close();
    }
  }
```

The code snippet above is working but as i mentioned, for every write i have to create a new connection.

When i initialize the `cassandraConnector` outside the loop, i make one successful write, and then i get "No hosts available" exceptions.

The CassandraConnector class:

```
 public class CassandraConnector {

  private final String KEYSPACE = "ba2";
  private final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
  private Cluster cluster;
  private Session session;

  public CassandraConnector() {
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(SERVER_IP).build();
    session = cluster.connect(KEYSPACE);
  }

  public void schreibeSensorDaten(Long key, SensorDaten datum) {

    try {

      session.execute(
          "INSERT INTO.....
```

Comment: Why don't you try to use Spark streaming for this case, spark streaming is relevant for Reading from Kafka then write to Cassandra or Hbase

Comment: @songoku1610 thanks for the input. have not heard about Spark before. Unfortunatly, i am only "allowed" to use Kafka and Cassandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to re-use the cluster/session instances - they are quite heavyweight regarding initialization...

It's also better to use [prepared statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/statements/prepared/) for data insertion - after you create a session, do something like:

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = session.prepare("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (?, ?)");
```

and then in the loop

```
session.execute(pStmt.bind(datum.key(), datum.value()));
```

Regarding the error, please check the logs on the Cassandra side.

Comment: thank you for your help. I adapted my code to your answer and it looks good. I also added the working solution as code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class SensorDatenKonsument implements Runnable {

  /** Kafka Konsument */
  private final KafkaConsumer<Long, SensorDaten> konsument;

  /** Einrichtung der Verbindung zu Cassandra */
  private final Cluster cluster =
      Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(TestKonfiguration.CASS_SERVER_IP).build();

  private final Session session = cluster.connect(TestKonfiguration.KEYSPACE);

  public SensorDatenKonsument(String groupId) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, TestKonfiguration.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(
        ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SensorDatenDeserializer.class.getName());
    this.konsument = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {


    try {
      konsument.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TestKonfiguration.TOPIC));
      PreparedStatement prepStmt =
          session.prepare(
              "INSERT INTO wetterdaten (id, date_time, air_temp, std_air_temp, humidity, std_humidity,"
                  + "IR_temp, std_IR_temp, air_pressure, std_pressure, wind_speed, std_wind_speed, light_A,"
                  + "std_light_A, light_B, std_light_B, distance, std_distance, counter, roll, pitch,"
                  + "X_accel, std_X_accel, Y_accel, std_Y_accel, Z_accel, std_Z_accel, battery, error,"
                  + "WDT_trace, crc3) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

      while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<Long, SensorDaten> kafkaRecord = konsument.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println("*** Poll ***");

        kafkaRecord.forEach(
            datum -> {
              session.execute(
                  prepStmt.bind(...
```

Comment: Just a small comments: if you have several machines, then it's better to use several contact points, something like `.addContactPoints(hosts.split(","))...`. You're connecting with explicit specification of keyspace - if in the future you'll have several keyspaces, then it's better to specify table as fully qualified (with keyspace), and do `connect` without it.